# when to use iloc and loc for boolean

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm a bit confusing when using boolean series for indexing for pandas Dataframe.
Should I use iloc or loc? or any better solution?
for example

```
t1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([3,4]))
t1.iloc[1:3,0]=3
```

this line will give correct answer

```
t1.loc[:,(t1>2).any()]
```

but line with iloc wiill raise an error

```
t1.iloc[:,(t1>2).any()]
```

I check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html, the page says both iloc and loc accept a boolean array. Why does iloc not work in my example? When to use iloc and loc? or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: While playing with your code, I found that converting the boolean series to list solves the problem. `t1.iloc[:,(t1>2).any().tolist()]`. This works with `loc` as well. Still have to figure out why.

Comment: And this is [not a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17454).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nuance is that `iloc` requires a Boolean **array**, while `loc` works with either a Boolean series or a Boolean array. The documentation is technically correct in stating that a Boolean array works in either case.

So, for `iloc`, extracting the NumPy Boolean array via [`pd.Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) will work:

```
t1.iloc[:, (t1>2).any().values]
```